# Relationship between coefficients and polynomial roots using induction proof?

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

let $p(x)$ be a polynomial  such that :

$ P(x) = a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots+a_{1}x + a_{0} $ with roots
$ r_{1}, r_{2}, \cdots , r_{n} $ , My question here is how to show that ($1$) is true using induction proof

$$\frac{1}{r_{1}} + \frac{1}{r_{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r_{n}} = -\frac{a_{1}}{a_{0}}\tag{1}$$
?.

**Note:** Really my attempt failed in the first step for initial condition

Comment: The base case (initial condition) is $n=1$, where $a_1 x + a_0= 0$ immediate gives the result. Now suppose you know the result for $n=k$ and use that to show it's true for $n=k+1$. Does that help?

Comment: Can you proceed by the hints given or you need some detail more?

Comment: @gimusi, Try to complet answer because the intial condition is clear to me i have a wrong reformulation of my note

Comment: I think you should state that roots are non-zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having a non-inductive proof, here it goes: let$$Q(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n.$$Then the roots of $Q(x)$ are the inverses of the roots of $P(x)$, that is, they are $\frac1{r_1},\frac1{r_2},\ldots,\frac1{r_n}$. And the sum of the roots of $Q(x)$ is $-\frac{a_1}{a_0}$.

Comment: I think he is asking for induction proof.

Comment: This is a very nice answer but not by induction.

Comment: @gimusi I missed that part of the question. I shall delete my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You could simply indicate that as a good alternative to the indiction way without deleting. For someone else it could be useful.

Comment: @gimusi That's a fine suggestion. I shall do that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I suggest you to let this answer to know more proofs

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

**Base case**

- $n=1\implies P(x)=a_1x+a_0=a_1(x-r_1)\implies a_0=-a_1r_1 \quad \frac1{r_1}=-\frac{a_0}{a_1}$

**Inductive step**

Assume true for $n$ that

$$\frac{1}{r_{1}} + \frac{1}{r_{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{r_{n}} = -\frac{a_{1}}{a_{0}}$$

and let

$$P_{n+1}(x)=a_{n+1}(x-r_{n+1})...(x-r_1)=(x-r_{n+1})P_n(x)$$

then indicating with $\bar a_1$ and $\bar a_0$ the coefficients for $P_{n+1}(x)$ we have

- $\bar a_1=a_0-r_{n+1}a_1$
- $\bar a_0=-r_{n+1}a_0$

and then

$$\frac{\bar a_1}{\bar a_0}=\frac{a_0-r_{n+1}a_1}{-r_{n+1}a_0}=-\frac1{r_{n+1}}+\frac{a_1}{a_0}$$

Comment: This is the definition of induction but how really could we show what to do when we wrote for $n+1$?

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar the OP say he had problem with the first step and of course I give an hint on that and on the general way. Should I post a full solution?

Comment: @gimusi, I meant I failed in the first step  that i can't do the following step ( All steps of induction)

Comment: @zeraouliarafik ok I try to add something more!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I'm going to add, it is not so difficult!